# How can I in Blender acces a polygon, which is given by indices, for an operator?

Tags: python, reference, blender

In `Blender 2.77` I have a polygon, referenced as:

```
 bpy.data.objects['Cube.001'].data.polygons[0]
```

and an operator:

```
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(0, 0, 1), constraint_axis=(False, False, False),  constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED',  proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1)
```

How can I make the operator be executed on the polygon?
I have tried:

```
 bpy.data.objects['Cube.001'].data.polygons[0].select = True
```

for selecting it, but it didn't seemed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While blender stores the mesh data within `object.data`, this data is only valid in object mode, when you switch to edit mode a bmesh copy of the mesh data is created, which replaces the `object.data` contents when you leave edit mode. As you are using a duplicate mesh while editing any selection changes you make to `object.data` with python will not effect the edit mesh and will be overwritten when exiting edit mode.

When you use `bpy.ops.transform.resize()` it works on the active item, this means for it to resize a polygon you need to be in edit mode. In object mode the same operator will resize the object.

So you could use

```
bpy.data.objects['Cube.001'].data.polygons[0].select = True
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(0, 0, 1))
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

but using bmesh is the preferred way to edit mesh data with python. You can find examples of using [bmesh here](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.html) and a more detailed example of editing the bmesh [data here](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.ops.html).

So a quick example that scales `face[0]` on the z axis would be -

```
import bpy
import bmesh

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(obj.data)

bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
bmesh.ops.scale(bm, verts=bm.faces[0].verts, vec=(0.0, 0.0, 1.0))

bm.to_mesh(obj.data)
bm.free()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to toggle back to OBJECT mode to do the ...polygons[0].select

```
# assume in EDIT... mode now
bpy.data.objects['Cube.001'].data.polygons[0]
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.data.objects['Cube.001'].data.polygons[0].select = True
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(0, 0, 1),
                     constraint_axis=(False, False, False),
                     constraint_orientation='GLOBAL',
                     mirror=False,
                     proportional='DISABLED',
                     proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH',
                     proportional_size=1)
```